# Delete video from vimeo api (not found)

Tags: video, vimeo

Im trying to delete video from vimeo using advanced API:

```
$vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.delete', xxxxx);
```

but I'm getting an error:

> 1: (The video id was either invalid or was for a video not viewable by the calling user.).

But the video exist and I can upload videos using advanced API why I can't delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons.

1. Your access token might not have delete permissions.
2. You might not have permissions to delete the video you are attempting to delete.

There are some ways you can help debug this.

1. Make sure the authenticated user is the owner of the  clip. You can check the authenticated user by making a request to vimeo.people.getInfo without any additional request parameters.
2. If you contact vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact with your access token (do not send your secret!) they can help verify the tokens permissions.